# Error when trying to migrate my databases

Tags: php, laravel, command, database-migration

This is the error I keep getting:

```
 desk git:(message) ✗ php artisan migrate:refresh

 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'migration' in 'order
 clause' (SQL: select * from `migrations` where `batch` is null order by 
 'migration` desc)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Add a column named migration to the migrations table? :D

Comment: the error is saying the actual problem.check the `migrations`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually delete all tables in your database. It's possible that one of your migrations has somehow changed the migrations table and it's causing this error. After deleting them, you can again:

```
php artisan migrate
```